# Chrome extensions "Options" window stopped functioning

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

On one of my computers, I can no longer change options in Chrome extensions (and some have just stopped working).

If I look in the Developer Tools: Javascript Console, the following shows up when loading the options windows for some extensions:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of null
```

Any ideas of what went wrong or how I should go about resolving this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to uninstall and then reinstall the wanton extensions. If that doesn't work, then reinstall Chrome. If that still doesn't work, use another browser and ask a professional geek about this. (By the way, Chrome is not very secure.)

Comment: By the way, if you're thinking about recompiling all the extensions, that likely won't help. You cannot compile a Chrome extension into Chrome without a special compiler (and I don't know where to find it).